# Can I include a Vue directive inside my .vue file when using vueify?

Tags: vue.js

When using the [vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify) package, is there a way I can include a directive inside my `SomeComponent.vue` file? It's a directive used only for that component. I tried including it inside the script tags outside the `export default { ... }` but it doesn't seem to work.

Am I stuck having all the directives in my main app.js file where I create the Vue instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html) show that you can include local directives using the `directives` option. I tried that and it worked fine.

Comment: How did you made it? If i try it with
directive(demo): {
        bind: function () {
            console.log('demo bound!')
        }
    },
The compiler gives me an unexpected token error.